# External Javascript file (Script.js) load form code behind asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to load javascript file form .aspx.cs page. Such as I have Script.js javascript file and load code behind(.aspx.cs) page .how can i load javascript form code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert on your page javascript code using

```
          ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
```

So you can include the entire .js content on your page. Here is a example including a Alert message to your page:

```
    var javaScriptCode = "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Hello!');</script>";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            javaScriptCode, false);
```